# Wordpress returns old thumbnail size after changing media settings

Tags: post-thumbnails, images, media-settings

I have had a requirement to update a WP build so that the thumbnail size changes from (the default) 150x150 to 500x500.

I've amended the size within the `Settings > Media` and utilised the awesome "Regenerate Thumbnails" plug-in to create the image files at the new sizes. So everything should be cool... alas not!

When I call my new image thumbnail `wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()),'thumbnail');` Wordpress is still returning my image as `...150x150.jpg` and not the new thumbnail size.

I've attempted updating the page/post in which the image appears but this doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Note: I am using a multi-site instance of Wordpress, but I've checked each instance to ensure that the images have been resized and that the settings have updated. Everything seems to be working correctly.

Comment: You should resize all your images after you changed the settings. https://wordpress.org/plugins/bulk-resize-media/

Comment: Yeah I did that... I have all of the images in the correct sizes, it just seems that WP still believes the 'thumbnail' size is the default.

Answer (score -1):

```
wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'medium' );
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to what your code does and how it should be used. Dumping code is not a quality answer if it even considred to be an answer